# How to select/Insert MySQL table from Oracle stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, oracle

Currently we have two oracle databases. One for ETL process and another one for OLAP process. Now we gonna move ETL Oracle instance to MySQL database. But our business logic  are written in PL/SQL.

Is there any possible way to access MySQL tables from oracle stored Procedure other than DB Link.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a database link over an ODBC connection to accomplish this. An example can be found at this [link](https://blog.pythian.com/how-to-access-mysql-from-oracle-with-odbc-and-sql/)

Alternative solutions would be creating an external process like a shell script that connects to MySQL, writes a flat file, and then bring that data into a temporary table in Oracle.

Comment: Yes. We can access by using DB link. But due to some restriction from our client we can't relay on DB Link. Any other ways or work around?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include one possible work around.  Connect to MySQL, write flat file, Connect to Oracle, create temporary table from flat file.